# Proving satisfiability using resolution and variable elimination

Tags: satisfiability

I don't 100% understand this. But I have a entailment, and I want to prove whether it is satisfiable or not, and I will do this using resolution and variable elimination.

Here is the formula:
$$
(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_6) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_3 \lor x_8) \land (\lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4) \land \\ (\lnot x_4 \lor x_5 \lor x_7) \land (\lnot x_4 \lor x_6 \lor x_8) \land ( x_5 \lor \lnot x_6) \land \\(\lnot x_6 \lor x_7 \lor \lnot x_8) \land (x_7 \lor \lnot x_8 \lor \lnot x_{10}) \vDash \lnot(x_7 \lor \lnot x_9 \lor x_{10})
$$
First I negate the conclusion and move it into the premises. If I can prove this to be ⊥ using Resolution, I have proven that the original entailment IS satisfiable. So this is what I want to refute by using resolutin (and variable elimination to simplify).

$$
(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_6) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_3 \lor x_8) \land (\lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4) \land \\ (\lnot x_4 \lor x_5 \lor x_7) \land (\lnot x_4 \lor x_6 \lor x_8) \land ( x_5 \lor \lnot x_6) \land \\(\lnot x_6 \lor x_7 \lor \lnot x_8) \land (x_7 \lor \lnot x_8 \lor \lnot x_{10}) \lor (x_7 \lor \lnot x_9 \lor x_{10})
$$

So I start off by eliminating all clauses with $x_7$ since it's a pure literal, which leaves me with

$$ (x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_6) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_3 \lor x_8) \land (\lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4) \land \\ (\lnot x_4 \lor x_6 \lor x_8) \land (x_5 \lor \lnot x_6) $$

Here $x_5$ is a pure literal, so that one clause can be removed.

$$ (x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_6) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_3 \lor x_8) \land (\lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4) \land (\lnot x_4 \lor x_6 \lor x_8) $$

Now $x_6$ is a pure literal, which would leave just the two clauses

$$ (\lnot x_1 \lor x_3 \lor x_8) \land (\lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4) $$

However, here $x_8$ is a pure literal, thus leaving us with only one clause, and that clause contains pure literals. Can it really be simplified into nothing? It feels like I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what it is that's wrong.

If I really can simplify into nothing, would that mean that the original formula is satisfiable or not satisfiable?

Since all the clauses contain a pure literal, wouldn't that make it impossible to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

If $x_7$ is a pure literal, then this means that you can satisfy all clauses containing $x_7$ by setting it to true. Accordingly, we set $x_7,x_5,x_6,x_8$ to true, satisfying all clauses apart from $\lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4$, which we can satisfy by setting $x_4$ to true (for example).

If you set $x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8$ to true, then the left-hand side of your original formula is satisfied (once you correct $x_1 \lor x_2$ to $x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_6$ and $\lnot x_5 \lor \lnot x_6$ to $x_5 \lor \lnot x_6$), while the right-hand side is falsified, and so the entailment is false. (In contrast to your post, there is no "formula" there which can be satisfied or not.)

Comment: Okay! Thank you for the answer. What I was trying to do was to prove whether the entailment is satisfiable, and I wanted to prove it using resolution + variable elimination. Moving the conclusion to the premises and then proving ⊥ using resolution would prove that the original entailment would be satisfiable. I'm just not quite sure how to prove it using Resolution.

Comment: Also I really appreciate the edit you made to my post, thank you! :)

Comment: You're checking whether the entailment is *refutable*, not satisfiable.

Comment: Resolution is a refutation system. It can prove that the entailment always holds, which isn't the case here.

Comment: I'm following this https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cbruni/CS245Resources/lectures/2018_Fall/06_Propositional_Logic_Resolution_Part_1_post.pdf at page 18. It says that if you negate the conclusion and convert it into CNF, and then refute that using Resolution, that means that the entailment is satisfiable.

Comment: There are 43 slides there. I'm not going to read all of them. Resolution can be used to prove that a CNF is unsatisfiable. In your case, the CNF states that the LHS is true while the RHS is false, that is, the entailment *does not* hold. You cannot use Resolution to prove that a CNF is satisfiable. Instead, just give a satisfying assignment.

Comment: Yes sorry, I accidently sent the comment before I was done

Comment: Maybe they're using a funny definition of "entailment is satisfiable". A truth assignment *satisfies* an entailment $p \to q$ if the truth value of $p \to q$ is True. An entailment is satisfiable if some truth assignment satisfies it.

Comment: An entailment $p \to q$ is satisfiable iff either $p$ is falsifiable or $q$ is satisfiable.

Comment: I think they use the definition that the entailment is satisfiable = there exists a mapping of truth value onto the literals where both sides become true.

Comment: I doubt it. Perhaps you should ask your TA?

Comment: I've really tried asking, but the course has ended so they don't have time to help me anymore :( I've really struggled to find answers regarding this subject. The book says "Given a formula φ in propositional logic, we say that φ is
satisfiable if it has a valuation in which is evaluates to T."

Comment: An entailment isn't really a formula, but if we regard $p \vDash q$ as the formula $p \to q$, then it is satisfiable if there is an assignment which satisfies $p \to q$. Using Resolution, instead you are trying to find out whether $p \land \lnot q$ is satisfiable, that is, whether $p \to q$ is falsifiable.

Comment: Re-imagine the question as "How would one solve whether (x1∨x2∨x6)∧(¬x1∨x3∨x8)∧(¬x2∨¬x3∨x4)∧(¬x4∨x5∨x7)∧(¬x4∨x6∨x8)∧(x5∨¬x6)∧(¬x6∨x7∨¬x8)∧(x7∨¬x8∨¬x10) is contradictory using resolution and variable elimination?" Because that's essentially what I'm having trouble with. I imagine you would first simplify with variable elimination (but how far? there are many pure literals.) and then finally solve it using resolution.

However you have helped a lot and I appreciate it, would understand if you don't want to put more time into it!

Comment: Use a SAT solver.